# When is the $SPUrl Token Prefix Needed?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, spurl

I have been doing some research and testing and found that the $SPUrl tokens (e.g. ~site and ~sitecollection) can be used in various scenarios to reference the root of the current site or web. However, I cannot seem to find information on when the $SPUrl prefix is required to reference these tokens.

For example, I know that when using a token like this in a CssRegistration control, we must use a syntax like so:

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssRegistration1" Name="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/custom.css %>" runat="server" />
```

However, I have also seen examples of using these tokens with a ScriptLink control that utilize the token with no $SPUrl prefix (and no <% %> tags) as follows:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink Language="javascript" Name="~sitecollection/SiteScripts/custom.js" runat="server" Localizable="false" />
```

Can someone explain why the <% %> tags and $SPUrl prefix are required in some situations but not others when using these tokens?